# Classic asp session variables disappears on redirect or page change

Tags: session, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an old site which has been working for years without an issue but this week the login to the admin panel for the site no longer works. I've traced it to a problem with session variables. Somehow they get unset on a page redirect.

Trying to figure out why  I created a couple of test pages:

```
<%
    Session("test") = "Hello World"
    Response.Write Session("test")
%>
<a href="test3.asp">go</a>
```

and

```
<%
    Session("test") = "Hello World"
    Response.Redirect = "test3.asp"
%>
```

With the test3.asp file:

```
<%
    Response.Write Session("test")
%>
```

Nothing gets printed when I get redirected to test3.asp or when I click on the link in the first file. I can see that the variable is set to "Hello World" in my first file.

I don't think anything has changed on the server in the past week when the sessions stopped working. The server is running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0.9200.16384.

Comment: Do you have Sessions enabled in IIS for the ASP Application? Could also be an overly aggressive App Pool Recycling policy. Does the ASP Application use SSL if so check `New ID on Secure Connection` in the ASP properties in IIS, if you switch between unsecured and secured connection the session will reset if this is set to `True`.

Comment: Sessions are enabled for ASP, and the site doesn't use SSL. I copied the files to a different site running on the same server and they work there. Is there a quick way to copy the settings from one site to another? Or should I simply delete the site a set it up again.

Comment: Have you tried this using multiple browsers? Sometimes this can happen if the browser does not accept your session coockie.